# Websocket Vue (sockjs-client and webstomp-client) and Spring CORS issue

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, vuejs2, spring-websocket

I tried to complete following [tutorial](https://sanaulla.info/2020/01/30/using-websocket-with-spring-framework-and-vuejs/).

BE code is practically the same, except for

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/connect").setAllowedOrigins("http://fe-machine-ip:8080").withSockJS();
}
```

FE code is a bit different cause I created a Vue project.

WebsocketView.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>

    <v-btn
      color="info"
      @click="connect"
    >
      Connect
    </v-btn>

    <v-btn
      color="success"
      @click="startTask"
    >
      Start Task
    </v-btn>

    <v-btn
      color="error"
      @click="stopTask"
    >
      Stop Task
    </v-btn>

    <v-btn
      color="primary"
      @click="disconnect"
    >
      Disconnect
    </v-btn>

    <v-card>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(message, i) in messages"
          :key="i"
        >
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>
              {{ message }}
            </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-card>

  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client'
import Stomp from 'webstomp-client'

export default {

  data () {
    return {
      stompClient: null,
      messages: []
    }
  },

  methods: {

    connect () {

      const socket = new SockJS('http://be-machine-ip:8080/connect')
      this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket)

      const ctx = this

      this.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {

        ctx.handleMessage('Connected')

        ctx.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', function (output) {
          ctx.handleMessage(output.body)
        })
      })
    },

    disconnect () {

      if (this.stompClient != null) {
        this.stompClient.disconnect()
        this.handleMessage('Disconnected')
      } else {
        console.log('Connect first')
      }
    },

    startTask () {

      if (this.stompClient != null) {
        this.stompClient.send('/ws/start')
      } else {
        console.log('Connect first')
      }
    },

    stopTask () {

      if (this.stompClient != null) {
        this.stompClient.send('/ws/stop')
      } else {
        console.log('Connect first')
      }
    },

    handleMessage (msg) {
      this.messages.push(msg)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Notice:** FE and BE are two distinct projects, running in two different PCs connected to the same network.

When I hit "Connect" I get this error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://be-machine-ip:8080/connect/info?t=1670429753007. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just opened my browser with wrong URL. I used

```
http://localhost:8080
```

instead of

```
http://fe-machine-ip:8080
```